# Eclipse JPA (MySQL) is autogenerate bit field to byte, can i make it generate bit to boolean

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jpa

In eclipse **JPA Entities from Tables** it's convert column **byte from mysql** to **byte in java**.

How can i change to boolean (Netbeans can generate correctly)?

Thanks in advance for answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Hmmmm. I don't see that the MySQL documentation says it has a data type of `BYTE`. Maybe you are mean `BIT`?]

Either way:

Dali (the part of Eclipse that generates JPA entities) uses DTP (another part of Eclipse) to determine the Java attribute type for a particular data type. These mappings are database platform-specific and are specified in `.xmi` files in various DTP plug-ins.

For example, for MySQL, the data type `BIT` (along with `BOOL` and `BOOLEAN`) is mapped to the Java type `byte` in the file
`/runtime/vendors/MySql_5.1/MySql_5.1.xmi`
in the plug-in jar
`./plugins/org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.mysql.dbdefinition_1.0.4.v201109022331`.

You can extract the appropriate `.xmi` file, edit it, and return it to its jar and this should alter how entities are generated.